# VB6 runtime error of MSFlexgrid

Tags: vb6

Whenever i run my project, it highlights the "Private Sub HighlightGridRow(grd As MSFlexGrid, iRow As Long)" row and pops up a box with the error message "User-defined type not defined". What can i do to make it work?

```
    Private Sub HighlightGridRow(grd As MSFlexGrid, iRow As Long)
    With grd
        If .Rows > 1 Then
            .Row = iRow
            .Col = 1
            .ColSel = .Cols - 1
            .RowSel = iRow
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: First test: create a new application, and in project menu add component and search for microsoft flexgrid. if it doesnt appear, you have not installed it yet. msflexgrid is a part of vb6, so you could you install vb6 without getting it? please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Peter Cooper Jr said, you probably don't have MSFlexGrid referenced in your project. To do that, go to Project -> Components, then check the box next to "Microsoft FlexGrid Control 6.0" if it's on the list. If not, you will have to click browse and manually add it.

If you can't find the ocx, just download it:

https://www.opendll.com/index.php?file-download=msflxgrd.ocx&arch=32Bit&version=6.0.84.18

Answer (score 3):

VB6 is not knowing what the type `MSFlexGrid` is, so it's assuming that it's a user-defined type that you haven't defined. More likely, you're trying to use a component that isn't referenced. You need to go to Components in the Project menu and add the Flex Grid component that you're trying to use.

This isn't quite an exact duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4677752/65839) since it's a different component missing, but you may be able to find more useful information there as well.

Answer (score 1):

Seems likely that `MSFlexGrid` is not a defined type, probably because you didn't add the OCX to the ToolBox.  Maybe the program uses `MSHFlexGrid` instead and you have copy/pasted code that doesn't fit?

Shouldn't have anything to do with the OCX not being registered.  That would more likely fail on an object creation exception instead.